Is possible to deploy apache-tika in a single jar using maven and javafx?
I´ve already finish a desktop application using IntelliJ, OpenJDK17, JavaFX17 in a project build with Maven.
The project runs well inside de IDE, the problems begin when I try to deploy the app in a single jar because I need a self-contained application runs from exe file..
The problems and errors I´m facing are:

A ClassNotFoundException with the launcher class that contains the main method, despite of I checked the POM and manifest.mf and it´s ok like other applications I´ve made before.
Other error was Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Thanks to other app I was working one I realised that the errors I´ve been experimented are related with the bouncyCastle libraries that Apache Tika uses so:

After I compiled the application in a single Jar,  I have unzip the jar and remove the files META-INF/*.SF' 'META-INF/*.RSA' 'META-INF/*DSA following the instructions I read here "Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar After that, I run the Jar and I don´t get the ClassNotFoundException and the application starts but Apache-Tika can´t parse any kind of document, so I can´t no use this option.

Following other comments in the previous link I tried to exclude this files during the compilation process with my POM but I´m using javafx-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin instead of maven-shade-plugin. So is not and option.

Other thing I also tried was compiled using jlink and moditec plugin but I have a lot of errors related to
Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink:

And I wasn´t able to fixed it.

And finally I create and artifact using the option in IntellIj "Jar files from libraries"- "copy to the output directory and link via manifest". In this case, the application run and work, but only because I have installed in my computer OpenJDK 17, and run from there, but I need a self-cointained application and create .exe file to execute in Windows. The problem is that, with javafx application I can´t create a working exe files if I dont wrap all the libraries in a single jar.
So, please, there are any genius around here that could help me with this issue? I´m trying for more than a month but I can´t find a solution.


I´ll share my POM if it could help

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sky</groupId>
  <artifactId>TikaParse</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TikaParse</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>     
 </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
                                    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.28</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.sky.tikaparse/com.sky.tikaparse.TikaAppLauncher</mainClass>
              <launcher>app</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
          </plugins>
  </build>
</project>```


In the title you say "Is possible to deploy apache-tika in a single jar", but in your question, you say "I need a self-contained application runs from exe file".  Those seem like different things to me.  Anyway, for your "single jar" see: Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing

Thanks for your answer. I said that because with a single jar, I can make a self-contained application, wrapping the jar in exe file using launch4j (telling where to look the JDK). I mean, I put in the same folder the .exe file created with launch4j and a copy of the JDK and It´s works.
But the problem it´s that I cant create the single jar with tika, because of the signatured files that use bouncyCastle

I don't know launch4j, but if it can create  .exe. for a single jar, it can probably create one for multiple.  Probably, if you want to use launch4j, a better approach than creating a single jar file, is to learn how to use the tool to work with multiple jar files, just my opinion.  I removed the jlink tag, as that doesn't seem relevant if you are using launch4j and copy of a non-jlinked jdk.

Related: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes exception while trying to run jar file. Also: Globally register bouncycastle security provider in JDK 11.  Please note, my comments are not answers, just suggestions for other resources you may wish to consider.

I´ve already read and test the first link. Following this advices I can run the application from my JAR and from my generated exe, but TIKA can not parse any document, so it´s not an option for me.
I´ve tried the second option, but It doesn´t work....

There is no reason why you can't register the bouncy castle security provider for JDK 11+ using the second link instructions.  If it "doesn't work", then it doesn't work for reasons apart from the bouncy castle registration.  Also if "TIKA can not parse any document" then it probably means something else is going wrong with your setup.  There isn't much additional at this stage that I think can be done to assist you in a forum such as StackOverflow.

When I said doesn´t work I mean I tried and get the same results. Tika doesn´t parse if I remove de signature files I said in my question. The application runs perfectly inside de IDE, the problems start when I try to compile, and specifically because what I have explained in my question. I can not believe anyone that uses tika haven´t experience similar errors, that´s why I also use StackOverFlow. Still I hope someone could answer my question.

To get help, make it so that somebody can replicate your issue, provide a [mcve].  Especially, you note in your question "with my POM" -> provide the complete pom.xml file.

See the comment on this question: Maven-shade tika-app returning empty string "You must be zapping the service files under META-INF that Tika needs. Look at the pom file for the Tika App itself to see an example of how to make a single jar of Tika without loosing key bits - Tika App is already a single jar shade" -> and that pom file is this. Looks complex to me.

Thanks, I'll try these options, despite of I have read in a post that it´s not recommended to use maven-shade-plugin with JavaFx applications instead of javafx-maven-plugin

FWIW, I created this uber jar file that includes JavaFX and Tika and it ran.  Whether it will help you accomplish your goal I don't know.  I don't use Tika at all, so did not test Tika functionality (parts of which may or may not work in the single jar configuration provided).
Resources used were:

Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing
tika app pom file

Code is NOT modular.  See openjfx getting started sections on non-modular application and runtime images for more explanation.
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tika</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parser-html-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-langdetect-optimaize</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-xmp</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-emitter-fs</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-async-cli</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.tika:tika-parsers-standard-package:jar:</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>LICENSE.txt</exclude>
                                        <exclude>NOTICE.txt</exclude>
                                        <exclude>CHANGES</exclude>
                                        <exclude>README</exclude>
                                        <exclude>builddef.lst</exclude>
                                        <!--  clutter not needed in jar  -->
                                        <exclude>resources/grib1/nasa/README*.pdf</exclude>
                                        <exclude>resources/grib1/**/readme*.txt</exclude>
                                        <exclude>resources/grib2/**/readme*.txt</exclude>
                                        <!--
                                         TIKA-763: Workaround to avoid including LGPL classes
                                        -->
                                        <exclude>ucar/nc2/iosp/fysat/Fysat*.class</exclude>
                                        <exclude>ucar/nc2/dataset/transform/VOceanSG1*class</exclude>
                                        <exclude>ucar/unidata/geoloc/vertical/OceanSG*.class</exclude>
                                        <!--  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3650 -->
                                        <exclude>javax/**/*</exclude>
                                        <!--  no idea why this is packaged as a jar within a jar  -->
                                        <exclude>rome-utils-2.1.0.jar</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.example.tika.TikaMain</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/LICENSE</resource>
                                    <file>target/classes/META-INF/LICENSE</file>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/NOTICE</resource>
                                    <file>target/classes/META-INF/NOTICE</file>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/DEPENDENCIES</resource>
                                    <file>target/classes/META-INF/DEPENDENCIES</file>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

